# Искать изменившиеся или новые файлы find ~

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер, find

Подскажите как лучше искать файлы, даже лучше не искать, а мониторить, файлы которые изменились или добавились за последний  час. или прямо сейчас.

я щас ищу так, за сутки.

```
find ~ -iname '*.php' -mtime -1
```

но наверное это не совсем верно? может есть какое то событие, которое можно отловить? на баше наверное врядли, ну хотябы на питоне

цель чтобы я всегда оперативно видел взломанные залитые шеллы

Comment: `git init` , `git add` , `git diff` - и будет счастье

Answer (score 7):

Бекапы или просто теневые копии (любая система контроля версий также хорошо поможет ещё и с откатом) - хорошее решение. Но если нужно просто высекать сам факт изменения, то можно сделать так.

Для начала проверим, что все работает. Запустите такую команду

```
inotifywait -mr /tmp # очевидно, нужно указать свой каталог
```

и попробуйте что-либо поделать в каталоге (даже ls будет достаточно). параметр m говорит "нужно мониторить", r - смотреть рекурсивно. Если все работает хорошо, можно перейти к скрипту. В принципе можно перехватывать вывод от этой команды и перенаправлять его скрипту для обработки, но можно и на питоне, будет неверно удобнее.

Bash (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542430/inotify-and-bash) - будем искать свежесозданные файлы и печатать в консоль имя и дату. В принципе уже достаточно, что бы сделать свою систему

```
DIR=/tmp
while RES=$(inotifywait -e create $DIR --format %f .)
  do echo RES is $RES at `date`; done
```

В принципе, inotifywait  умеет печатать в syslog, а на него можно направить любую систему анализа логов (splunk, elk), а там уже делать систему нотификации нужных людей.

Python - есть модуль с примером https://pypi.org/project/inotify/

---

Если же хостер не позволяет, используйте git или hg (или любую другую систему контроля версий). А по таймеру (крону) вызывайте git status и смотрите на вывод. Либо смотрите [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139290/how-to-check-if-theres-nothing-to-be-committed-in-the-current-branch).

Но никто не мешает делать `git checkout . && git clean -fd` и нам побоку на юних хацкеров:)

Comment: да видимо то что надо, но не установлена у хостера. вообщем только наверно для своего сервера подойдет. в принципе да то что надо

Comment: нормального хостера всегда можно попросить

Comment: тож верно попробую

Comment: неа не дают, говорят на vps переходите